# Pandas to_datetime returns error for perfectly fine python time

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

So I have a bunch of data that has timestamps in python epoch time format, however using this to_datetime() function returns `ValueError: unconverted data remains: 00`

Here's the code

```
import pandas as pd

print pd.to_datetime('1451080800', format='%Y%m%d')
```

What's going wrong here ?

Comment: That `'1451080800'` is not of the format ``'%Y%m%d'``? Do you want `pd.to_datetime(int('1451080800'), unit='s')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say it is epoch time, I think you want this:

```
In [44]: pd.to_datetime(int('1451080800'), unit='s')
Out[44]: Timestamp('2015-12-25 22:00:00')
```

Note the `int(..)` around the string. When specifying a `unit` (epoch is in seconds since 1970), the argument needs to be an integer.